# In Oracle SQL developer, why are all options to create tables, views and whatnot greyed out?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL developer, why are all options to create tables, views and whatnot greyed out?

I have tried a couple different databases and the result is the same.

But when I use Toad for oracle, I am able to create tables on the same databases.

Comment: do you log on as the same user, on both Toad & SQL developer?

Comment: I don't login as the same user at the same time.  but I have tried using sysdba role on both program.   Toad I can create  and in SQL Developer, still read-only

Comment: Try to run SQL Developer as Administrator, right click on shortcut than "Run as Administrator". (not sure it will work).

Comment: Not able to 'run as administrator'.... but it worked before as non-administrator

Answer (score 0):

Though old, this was the one that came up first for me...

In SQL Developer 4.0.3.16 on OSX, I noticed this when creating a new schema/database in MySQL.  Create database worked, but when I right-clicked on "Tables", the "New table..." option was greyed out.

"File -> New..." opens a dialog I wasn't familiar with, and under "Database Tier" was an option "Database Objects".

Everything visible in the dialog was greyed out.  But when you scroll down, the items "Table" and "View" were available.  Double-clicking on "Table" opens the GUI table creation dialog.

Note that in the workspace, the "CREATE TABLE..." DDL command worked, but I was specifically looking for the table creation dialog.

Why the "New table..." option on the context dialog was unavailable is still a mystery.

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

(This is for version 21.4.3.063) In 'Connections', ensure that you have selected/highlighted the database you want to create the object in (it is not enough to have the database selected in the SQL Worksheet). Then when you go to the Database Objects in the 'New Gallery' they will no longer be greyed/dimmed.